# Google reCaptcha v2 PHP - works only with file_get_contents()

Tags: php, post, recaptcha

I am new to PHP and trying to implement Google reCaptcha v2 using PHP and AJAX using either `CurlPost()` or `SocketPost()` methods. Currently everything runs fine with `file_get_contents()` but my provider is going to lock it down soon so I need to refactor my code. Somehow I ran into problem with implementing `CurlPost()` or `SocketPost()` - whenever I try to use either of them, nginx responds with 403 stating that `Not a POST request` (it is hardcoded in one of the `else` clauses).

What exactly did I overlook with `POST`? Below are two pieces of code, one is working perfectly with `file_get_contents()` and second is code in question throwing 403.

Working one

```
<?php

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
    require("PHPMailer.php");
    require("Exception.php");
    require("SMTP.php");
    require('recaptcha-master/src/autoload.php');
            if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
            $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
                    $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
            $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
            $tel = trim($_POST["tel"]);
            $message = trim($_POST["message"]);
        $recaptchaSecret = "6LcjwkUUAAAAAENXcZtla40jNuPJGblZkYxLkXvf";
        $captcha = '';
        if(isset($_POST["captcha"]) && !empty($_POST["captcha"])){
        $captcha=$_POST["captcha"];
        }
        if(!$captcha){
              echo 'Prove that you are human';
              exit;
            }
                $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=6LcjwkUUAAAAAENXcZtla40jNuPJGblZkYxLkXvf&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
        $obj = json_decode($response);

         if($obj->success == true) {
            // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
            if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR empty($tel) OR empty($captcha) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
                http_response_code(400);
                echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
                exit;
            }

            // Build the email content.
            $email_content = "Имя: $name\n";
            $email_content .= "Телефон: $tel\n";
            $email_content .= "Email: $email\n";
            $email_content .= "Сообщение: $message\n";

            // Send the email.

        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        //Server settings
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
            $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
            $mail->Host = 'domain.tld';               // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username = 'info';                     // SMTP username
            $mail->Password = 'password';             // SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
            $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        //Recipients
            //$mail->setFrom($name, $email);
            $mail->setFrom('info@domain.tld', 'DOMAIN.TLD');
            $mail->addAddress('info@domain.tld', 'Information');  // Add a recipient
            $mail->addReplyTo('info@domain.tld', 'Information');

        //Content
            $mail->Subject = 'Новое сообщение с сайта DOMAIN.TLD' ;
            $mail->Body    = $email_content;

        $success = $mail->send();
            echo "success"; 
        }
        } else {
            // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
            http_response_code(403);
            echo "Something went wrong. Please try again";
       }
?>
```

And not working, giving 403:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
require("PHPMailer.php");
require("Exception.php");
require("SMTP.php");
require('recaptcha-master/src/autoload.php');
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
                $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $tel = trim($_POST["tel"]);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);
        $recaptcha = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];
        $secret = '6LcjwkUUAAAAAENXcZtla40jNuPJGblZkYxLkXvf';
        }
    //$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\CurlPost());
    $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\SocketPost());
    $resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

    if ($resp->isSuccess()) {

        // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
        if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR empty($tel) OR empty($recaptcha) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
            exit;
        }

        // Build the email content.
        $email_content = "Имя: $name\n";
        $email_content .= "Телефон: $tel\n";
        $email_content .= "Email: $email\n";
        $email_content .= "Сообщение: $message\n";

        // Send the email.

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'domain.tld';               // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'info';                     // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'password';             // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('info@domain.tld', 'DOMAIN.TLD');
        $mail->addAddress('info@domain.tld', 'Information');  // Add a recipient
        $mail->addReplyTo('info@domain.tld', 'Information');

    //Content
        $mail->Subject = 'Новое сообщение с сайта DOMAIN.TLD' ;
        $mail->Body    = $email_content;

    $success = $mail->send();
        echo "success"; 

    } else {
        // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "Something went wrong. Please try again";
   }
?>
```

Really thankful for any hints! Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the second script you never send the post parameters.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Looks like that, but I cannot figure out where the error is :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found working solution with `curl` not using standard google recaptcha library, just plain `curl`. The code needs a lot of cleaning but it's working. Here it is:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
require('PHPMailer.php');
require('Exception.php');
require('SMTP.php');
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST['name']));
                $name = str_replace(array('\r','\n'),array(' ',' '),$name);
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST['email']), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $tel = trim($_POST['tel']);
        $message = trim($_POST['message']);
        $secret = '6LcjwkUUAAAAAENXwZtla40jNuPJGblZkYxLkXvf';
        $captcha = '';
        if(isset($_POST['captcha']) && !empty($_POST['captcha'])){
        $captcha=$_POST['captcha'];
        }
        if(!$captcha){
          echo 'Prove that you are human';
          exit;
        }
        $fields = array(
            'secret'    =>  $secret,
            'response'  =>  $_POST['captcha'],
            'remoteip'  =>  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
        );

        $verifyResponse = curl_init('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
        curl_setopt($verifyResponse, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($verifyResponse, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
        curl_setopt($verifyResponse, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
        $responseData = json_decode(curl_exec($verifyResponse));
        curl_close($verifyResponse);

    if ($responseData->success) {

        if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR empty($tel) OR empty($captcha) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo 'Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.';
            exit;
        }
        // Build the email content.
        $email_content = 'Имя: $name\n';
        $email_content .= 'Телефон: $tel\n';
        $email_content .= 'Email: $email\n';
        $email_content .= 'Сообщение: $message\n';
        // Send the email.
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'domain.tld';                           // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'info';                             // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'password';                         // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
    //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('info@domain.tld', 'DOMAIN.TLD');
        $mail->addAddress('info@domain.tld', 'Information');  // Add a recipient
        $mail->addReplyTo('info@domain.tld', 'Information');
    //Content
        $mail->Subject = 'Новое сообщение с сайта DOMAIN.TLD' ;
        $mail->Body    = $email_content;

    $success = $mail->send();
        echo 'success'; 
        }
    } else {
        http_response_code(403);
        echo 'Something went wrong. Please try again';
   }
?>
```